# How is it possible to interate within a ElementRef.nativeElement

Tags: angular, single-page-application, angular-directive

I have a case which i decided to use a directive that needs to access the an ElementRef in order to manupulate the dom via Renderer.

At this point, since the Direcive placed on HTML element which is under *ngFor loop, when the directive call the elemenRef.nativeElement it gets a whole bouch of them (obviously one for each iteration of the *ngFor).

Is there a way to filter the nativeElements by ID or any sort of selection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using renderer you can try this:

In your html file:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of elements">
   <div [attr.id]="element.id"></div>
</div>
```

This will asing a id to every element in the *ngFor loop.
Then in your ts file:

```
let element = this.renderer.selectRootElement(`#${id}`);
```

Comment: Thanks Albert, 
It seems to work but it selects as many as elements exist in the DOM under the parent, in my current case 15 times, is the a way to select only the first result?

Comment: I refactor my application,  this approach actually saved me a directive

Thanks bud

Comment: why not use ViewChildren????

Comment: As for being new to angular i was s truggle with so much all together, I was looking for a simple solution to manipulate DOM props and CSS classes, to be honest so far all i needed is a ViewChild for static elements.
Thanks